# How to replace flex in this layout?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I'm trying to do a responsive design for a menu, you can see the code **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/ej7ayq4y/)**.

As you can see flex works pretty well for that design. My only concern is that it won't be compatible with older browsers. Is there an easy way of implementing this without flex, I have tried having only divs inside a container **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/ggb2ecu7/)**

The problem is I don't know how to make the My log box appear beside the New log box.

I want to keep responsiveness (boxes stacking up vertically in smaller screens).

Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="block-menu vertical">

        <div class="menu-item">My organizations</div>

        <div class="block-menu horizontal">

            <div class="block-menu vertical">

                <div class="menu-item">
                    ITPs
                </div>

                <div class="menu-item">
                    My log
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="menu-item">

                New log

            </div>


        </div>

        <div class="menu-item">
            Profile
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.block-menu.horizontal {

    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div.block-menu.horizontal > div {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

div.block-menu.vertical {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

div.block-menu.vertical > div.menu-item {
    width: auto;
}

.menu-container div.menu-item {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add one extra div (like it is in the flex example), it is kind of simple playing with the values for `float` and `width`, you can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ggb2ecu7/3/

Although that one doesn't take into account the margin that you have in the flex example. To fix that, you could use `calc`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ggb2ecu7/4/ (sorry about the extra unnecessary CSS rules). E.g.:

```
.w2 {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

[20px because the margin I set was 10px  (on both sides = 20px)]

The problem with calc is that it may not work with all the older versions. You can check the support for calc in here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc